# Autocomplete field with a personalized library

Tags: java, swing

i'm currently working on a project which consists on creating a java swing app for the management of a veterinary clinic. i want to add in the animal file an autocomplete field that can suggest me the name of the medecine i want to write without writing the whole name !! i already have a DB for the medecines the clinic provides soo what i want to do is to make the DB the base of the autocomplete field library... i'm using netbeans btw

How can i make this happen if it's possible !! i hope you can help !!

Comment: Did you tried some code?

Comment: just use jtextfield and a jlist. use key press event in jtextfield and search names using like query for the entered text. add those results to jlist and for the click event in jlist add clicked item to jtextfield.

Comment: Has your problem been resolved? You removed your comment that you would try out the solution from @DualCoreMax.

Comment: i'm sorry i certainly didn't remove my comment i have no idea what happened and for the solution i've tried the jlist idea it was alright it worked but i guess the solution *according to the code below* is better soo i'm gonna try it and see ^^

Answer (score 0):

I tought that this piece of code may help you:

```
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;

    import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

    public class StackOverflow 
    {
        private static final List<String> suggestions = Arrays.asList("Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Dolphin");

        public static void main(final String[] arguments) 
        {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("StackOverflow Question | Demo");
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> 
            {
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(400, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
                frame.setVisible(true);
                final JLabel label = new JLabel();
                final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
                textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frame.getContentPane().getWidth(), textField.getFont().getSize() * 2));
                textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) 
                    {
                        String suggestion = "";
                        for (String str : suggestions) {
                            if (str.toLowerCase().startsWith(textField.getText().toLowerCase())) 
                            {
                                suggestion += str + ", ";
                            }
                        }
                        label.setText(suggestion.isEmpty() ? suggestion : suggestion.substring(0, suggestion.length() - 2));
                    }
                });
                frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
                frame.getContentPane().add(label);
                frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
            });
        }
    }
```

This is an example on how you can implement a field with autocompletion. You can add every possible suggestion into the `suggestions` list.